# Copy data from sqlite table row to a virtual table row

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am new to SQLite and am having trouble with a search routine I am writing in VB. I have a table that stores persons (name, dob, address, phone number, description, etc.). My search routine creates a virtual table (using fts5 module) which has identical columns as my persons table.

Let's say the user wants to search by gender and description. I am beginning the search by finding everyone with a matching gender. I was then going to place the search results into a virtual table, which can then be searched for anyone with a matching description.

I have it where it is creating the virtual table and locating everyone with a matching gender, but I am having trouble placing those search results into the virtual table. I figure I can copy the data column by column but thought there may be an easier way?

The below is my code.

```
Try
    'opens the database connection
    If (OpenDBConn() = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sqliteExecCmd = GlobalVar.dbConn.CreateCommand()
    sqliteExecCmd.CommandText = "**THE COMMAND THAT FINDS EVERYONE BASED ON INITIAL SEARCH**"

    sqliteReader = sqliteExecCmd.ExecuteReader()
    sqliteExecCmd.Dispose() 'disposes of read command after it has been used

    Using sqliteReader
        While sqliteReader.Read
            'THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PLACE ANY LOCATED RECORD(S) INTO THE VIRTUAL TABLE
        End While
    End Using

    sqliteReader.Close() 'closes reader
Catch ex As Exception
    'closes connection if it is left open
    If (GlobalVar.dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        CloseDBConn() 'closes the db connection
    End If

    DisplayError(ex.ToString, "SearchNoc")
End Try

CloseDBConn() 'closes the db connection
```

Comment: Instead of using SqlDataReader, you can use a SqlDataAdapter to store the results in a datatable. You can then perform different ways of filtering on that datatable using dataviews.

Comment: Thank you for that idea @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, I have been exploring using that method for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in few cases you will and need to query/filter against data you "already" pulled from SQLite.

However, any simple query in .net can near always be returned as an "in memory" table, and you can filter against those results. However, in most cases, it is preferred to re-query against the database. And with indexing, you often get better performance, and wind up using less memory anyway.

So, take a simple list of hotels. I might want to search by City, and then maybe by Hotel Name (wild card - starting with letter).

So, say this simple form:

[image]

So, in above, we pulled the first dataset (City).

Then, we wanted to filter more.

However, I did not filter against the first data pull, since it really does not help much.

So, code behind looks like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description FROM tblHotels
        WHERE City Like @City And HotelName like @Hotel
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", DbType.String).Value = txtCity.Text & "%"
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel", DbType.String).Value = txtHotel.Text & "%"

    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL)


End Sub


Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SQLite.SQLiteCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using con As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(My.Settings.Hotels)

        cmdSQL.Connection = con
        Using (cmdSQL)
            con.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Now, in above, I simply used a wild card (starting with) like match.

However, I suppose I could re-write the above, and say pull the data table of City, and then filter on the datatable = HotelName for the 2nd criteria.

As noted, in most cases, this is not worth the trouble, and with high-speed database indexing, then hitting the database engine again for the second criteria is not only a fine approach, but often recommended.

However, let's change the code to pull by City, and THEN filter against the results in the data table (DataTable is a in memory table, and is rather handy for this case).

So, now the code becomes this:

```
Dim rstData As DataTable

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description FROM tblHotels
        WHERE City Like @City 
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", DbType.String).Value = txtCity.Text & "%"

    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData


End Sub



Private Sub cmdFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdFilter.Click

    rstData.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"[HotelName] Like '{txtHotel.Text}%'"

End Sub
```

So, note how we scoped the data table to the form, and thus filter against that data table, and do not re-pull the data again.

So the form now looks like this:

[image]

So, one can filter against the data table we first pulled from the database. However, in practice, it is often better to just re-pull from the database, and filter against the database, since the query system can use indexing, where as filtering against the in-memory table (DataTable object) does not use indexing.

## Edit 3: Follow up (good) queston: How to filter for many options

Ok, so the next great quest is to filter for "many" things.

However, we want to avoid the "huge" increasing complexity. Remember, with 5 optional queries? Then recalling high school math (combinations, permutations, and probability)?  That mean n! or in this case 5! = 120 possible filter combinations. If you have just 8 optional filters, then that is 8! = 40,320 possible filter combinations!

However, there is a nice approach that can avoid all the combinations for "many" optional filters.

And while we could use simple basic string concentations to build the SQL, we STILL MUST use safe paramter code to prevent SQL injection risks. For a simple desktop applcation, we "might" risk this, but for web based, we STILL must use paramter safe SQL code.

So, the trick is to then "build up" the filter, and "build up the SQL", and do so with parameter's.

Few know/realize that parameter's can be created BEFORE and without the SQL existing yet!

So, say this filter screen, and ALL OF the filter options are 100% optional (leave them blank - they mean "all" or "ignore").

While this example is web based, and this example is for SQL server and not SQLite?

The approach is 100% the same.

Hence this:

[image]

So, in above, we have 6 optional filters for the data grid.

The code behind looks like this for the filter:

```
Sub LoadByFilter()

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels"
    Dim strOrderBy As String = " ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim strWhere As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("")

    If cboCity.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        strWhere = "(City = @City)"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text
    End If

    If cboProvince.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= "(Province = @Prov)"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Prov", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboProvince.SelectedItem.Text
    End If


    ' must have description
    If chkDescripiton.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Description is not null)"
    End If

    If chkActiveOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Active = 1)"
    End If

    If chkBalconyOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Balcony  = 1)"
    End If

    If chkWaterOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (LakeView  = 1)"
    End If



    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strSQL &= " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If

    strSQL &= " " & strOrderBy
    cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Note VERY close the above design pattern. We can have 1, or 20 filters. We just keep adding to the end of the filter routine.

For each "filter" option on the page:

We add some SQL. We add a parameter (when user input).

We then pull the data table, and bind it to the Gridview (in web land, we have to set data source AND ALSO set DataBind. In desktop land, the 2nd databind is not required.

So, as above shows, we can now have 1 or 15 filters. We just keep adding all them up, and if the filter option in question is left blank (not used), then we ignore it. That way we avoid the n! complexity issue with multiple combinations of SQL code.

Note also how we are still able to use injection safe parameter's in above, and they are also optional added to the code. As I stated, the above example is for SQL server, so you have to tweak it a bit to work for SQL, but the overall concept is the same.

Comment: Wow, that is quite an explanation, thank you very much. It sounds like I need to get better at writing queries. So for my needs, I have a lot of different possible search criteria, probably anywhere from 1 to 20. If the user wants to search as many as 20 criteria is it typical to have a SQL query that long?

Comment: see my edit 3 for how to deal with multiples filters....